# mdsliders move together on kivymd unintentionally

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

so I have multiple mdsliders on my mdscreen and when I move one slider the others also move can you tell me why? or how to fix it?

MDSlider:
value: 55
max: 60
hint_bg_color: "red"
hint_text_color: "white"
hint_radius: [6, 0, 6, 0]
size_hint_x: .7
pos_hint: {"center_x": .6,"center_y": .8}
here is one of the many sliders. I tried separating them by using id but it didn't work

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].